# how to handle activities configuration change

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

what i need is i have 3 activities i have navigated from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3. now at i am at third screen and now if i press home button all the activities will be paused and application goes into background. and when i open the app by long press on home buttton passcode screen will appear and when entered pas code now i need to get 3rd activity screen from where i pressed home button. How can i do this. how could i do this

i referred [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android) this link

Comment: @sandeep could you suggest me some thing regarding this question